# entity framework same model different tables

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, multiple-tables

Problem: Save same kind of aggregated statistics for web api calls for different time units (hour, day etc.).

All the aggregated information will contain the same kind of information. Something along the lines of:

```
public class AggregatedStatistics
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int Hits { get; set; }
    public int CachedHits { get; set; }
}
```

Since I would like to aggregate stats for different time units I would like to keep each time unit in a separate table. Reason being that it would a) make lookups faster and b) less risk of accidentally using wrong data. I am not experienced with databases so I do not know if either point really is a concern. I guess the latter should not be, and the former depends on the amout of data.

So, what is a good way to accomplish what I am after? I guess one solution that might work is to make the above class abstract and inherit from it (if that would work in EF Code First). That seems kind of semi-ugly though since no more members would be added to the class.

Comment: question is vague and for me confusing. Just use N tables. 1 per time unit. If Timestamp make sense as "time unit" bucket , yes inheritance can be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.4